# From which tribe were the Mapilim of Num 14:40?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, shevatim-12-tribes, parashat-shelach

A number of Jews tried to enter eretz yisroel after the incident of the spies (see [Bamidbar 14:40](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0414.htm#40)-45). I would like to know from which tribe they came. I know that at least one person may have been tzlafchad ([Shabbat 97a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=97&format=pdf)). Were the rest from his tribe?

Comment: The fact that you are specifically referring to them as *ma'pilim* and asking about their tribe makes me suspect that your question is motivated by the existence of Bnei Akiva's שבט מעפילים. Are you perhaps instead thinking about the attempted settlement of part of the tribe of אפרים in ארץ ישראל before the rest of the Jews were redeemed from Egypt (see *Sanhedrin* 92b; Rashi ad loc.; [*Pirkei d'Rabbi Eliezer* 47](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27744); and other sources)? If so, Tz'lofchad was from the tribe of M'nashe (though also from Yosef). Is something else motivating this question?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! As @Fred implies, [edit]ing into your question your motivation for asking it may help answerers better focus their answers on precisely what you seek. I hope you enjoy the site and stick around. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: To sum up my above comment perhaps more clearly: Why would you think that those people were from a single tribe?

Comment: @Fred I don't know if they come from mayor just one tribe. I'm just curious to know their identity